# Why is compiling drivers for the Ralink RT3070 wireless chipset failing?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, compiling, ralink

I'm attempting to compile drivers for my Telewell TW-WLAN 802.11g/n USB adapter, but I'm getting [an error](http://pastie.org/private/kl1lokm0srld3wwvaqj9a) I cannot solve during the make. I'm following [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035156).

I can get the adapter to work with built in rt2x00usb but it's stuck in G mode instead of N, which was the whole point of acquiring this piece of hardware.

Steps I've done so far:

- Edit blacklist.conf & reboot to unload the built in drivers
- Grab the files required for compiling (2008_1225_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.0.1.0)
- Installed build tools with `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`
- Changed WPA supplicant settings from n to y in config.mk

If anyone could check the error I'm getting and help me overcome it, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *very old* version of the driver, hence the errors.

The latest is 2.5:

```
2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
```

Get it from http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5016 . It [builds successfully.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1148642/)

Comment: Compiled and the drivers work -- but still stuck in G instead of N. Thanks for the help anyway.